# What are one-to-one onto functions?

Tags: function, one-to-one, discrete-mathematics

We have been told about this function: a combination of a one-to-one and onto, our teacher called it ("one-to-one onto function"). But I am skeptical about it, because I can't find such word or its definition on the web.

Maybe our teacher is mistaken about this topic; maybe it doesn't really exist.

What do you think?

Comment: I know about this one to one and onto functions but this sort of combination of one to one onto functions I can't find it's definition.

Comment: I think "proof" is a mathematical approach. The word you're looking for is "prof", and he's right.

Comment: "onto" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function, "one to one" is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function; combined they form a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection. Read more on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection,_injection_and_surjection. Also - so not a programming question.

Comment: In all probability, it is the usual bijective function. I  have seen one to one and onto function written as one one onto function in many places.

Comment: @Jayseer basically it's a function that assigns exactly one value on its range to each value in its domain.

Comment: ahh ok! thank you guys it is more clearer to me now It is called bijection.

Answer (score 1):

In the usual terminology, "one-to-one" means that different points in the domain always map to different points in the range and "onto" means that for every point in the range, there is some point in the domain that maps to it.

A function with both properties is normally called a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection); the function has an inverse that has exactly the same properties of one-to-one and onto.

Comment: @axiom - Who knows? I did point out that a one-to-one onto function is normally called a bijection. Perhaps that term is what OP was looking for. (I see that you and Amadan made the same point at about the same time.)

Answer (score 1):

[image]
<sub>(source: [regentsprep.org](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP5/onetoone.jpg))</sub>
one to one function

[image] not one to one function

[image] onto function

[image]
<sub>(source: [regentsprep.org](http://www.regentsprep.org/Regents/math/algtrig/ATP5/surjectiveNO.gif))</sub>

not onto function